# My binary search for seeing if an integer is in an array is looping forever, does anyone know why? (in Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, while-loop, binary-search

My binary search for seeing if an integer is in an array is looping forever, does anyone know why this might be occurring? By the way, I am using a binary search for the first time.

My Java code is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testBeforeLearning {
        private int[] array;
        private int target;

        public testBeforeLearning(int[] array, int target){
            this.array = array;
        }

        private int low;
        private int high;
        private int mid;

        public Boolean actualSearch(){
            low = 0;
            high = array.length - 1;

            while (target != array[mid]){
                mid = (low + high)/2;

                if (target == array[mid]){
                    return true;
                }

                else if(target > array[mid]){
                    low = mid + 1;
                }
                else if (target < array[mid]){
                    high = mid - 1;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int[] dataSet = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

            System.out.println("Please input a number you want to search for in the array:\n");

            int target = input.nextInt();

            testBeforeLearning binarySearch = new testBeforeLearning(dataSet, target);
            System.out.println(binarySearch.actualSearch());

    }
}
```

For some reason, my lower and upper bounds don't seem to be increasing or decreasing, and I am not sure why, does anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've set your while condition to be target != array[mid]. But since target is uninitialized (defaults to 0) and 0 does not exist in the array, it will go on forever.
you have to set the value of target in testBeforeLearning. On a side note, you should probably also make the while condition low <= high.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This helped me end the infinite loop, but it still gave me a weird return value. It returned 'false' when I searched for 8 in the array, do you know why?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I forgot to do this.target = target in the constructor class, I just did this.array = array.